# Laravel and Custom socket

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, hex, lumen

I have created Laravel Lumen project which receives API requests from my front-end. The request contains a hex string. What I need to do is I have to convert a hex string to a byte array and send it through specific IP and Port with a socket connection. I don't know the structure of the socket server but I needed to connect to the socket server and send my byte array. My problem is my approach is failing.

```
class TwoController extends Controller
{
    public function sendRequest(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $v = $this->validate($request, [
                'hex' => 'required',
            ]);

            $host = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";
            $port = 6090;
            $timeout=15;
            $sk = fsockopen($host, $port, $errnum, $errstr, $timeout);

            if(!is_resource($sk)){
                exit("connection fail: " . $errnum . " " . $errstr);
            } else {
                $array = hex2ByteArray($v['hex']);
                fwrite($sk, $array);
                echo fread($sk, 6);
                fclose($sk);
            }
        } catch(ValidationException $e){
            return response()->json($e->errors(), 422);
        } catch(Exception $e){
            return response($e->getMessage(), 500);
        }

    }
}
```

It is my method of converting hex2ByteArray

```
  function hex2ByteArray($hexString) {
    $string = hex2bin($hexString);
    return unpack('C*', $string);
  }
```

**UPDATE 1:**
Thank you to those who commented on my problem. I figured out that my client's server is not running properly. I contacted the client and told them to restart the server. Now I'm receiving responses from the socket sever. I'm not sure that I'm sending right byte of data. The response they gave me is also byte. I send the response to the serial port machine and wait for it to do the magic. If it says it is correct then it is correct. I will update you when I found out what is the right response and the right request.

Comment: You could skip `$string = hex2bin($hexString);` and just try `unpack('h*', $hexString);` or `unpack('H*', $hexString);`

Comment: Do you have an error message or stack trace that you could show us?